# Adding JavaFx to an applet

Tags: java, applet, javafx

Hello everyone i am quite new to JavaFx and is currently creating my programs with JavaFx Scene builder. i have never been a pro at creating GUI's and therefore the JavaFx Scene builder allows me to optimize the visual effects!

Ive been given an assignment at work to create an applet for one of our companies websites, the content of the applet should be a graph that will show some detailed information.

Since i enjoy JavaFx and and i find the graphs that you can create in JavaFx and manipulate in CSS quite awesome i wanted to use JavaFx to create my applet.

My Question is however am i able to use JavaFx scene builder to create my applet aswell or am i forced to write to code from scrats?

Also on a side note does anyone know any tutorials on how to apply JavaFx to an Applet ive been looking for some on Google but i only found some pretty advanced guides?

**EDIT**

I did find a tutorial on Applets for JavaFx however it did not state anything about JavaFx Scene builder

Link: [JavaFx Applet tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-compiled-javafx-apple)

Comment: First work through [Packaging and Deploying JavaFX Applications in the Browser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/1.3/tutorials/deploy-applet/) which might answer your question.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson Thank you for your response Andrew however can you answer me if i can use JavaFx Scene builder and deploy the FXML file aswell?

Comment: No (I cannot answer that).  I have not delved into Java FX yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use JavaFX scene builder with applets, I work as a website administrator for an educational project that require applets to plot graphs, communicate with hardware and look nice and stay secure and hard to download; that is why we are using JavaFX for most of our applets.

Even though I am not involved in the applet making process but I know for a fact that we use JavaFX scene builder to create the graphical user interface.

Also the main reason for creating JavaFX and JavaFX scene builder was for creating applets, because this is what Oracle intended from the sart.